# How to check if an element contains multiple items in Cypress.io

Tags: testing, cypress

How can I check if an element contains multiple items in Cypress.io without replicating my code so much?

Current Example:

```
cy.get(".column")
  .children()
  .contains("Name");

cy.get(".column")
  .children()
  .contains("Age");

cy.get(".column")
  .children()
  .contains("Weight");

cy.get(".column")
  .children()
  .contains("Height");

cy.get(".column")
  .children()
  .contains("Favorite Color");
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
cy.get('.column')
  .children()
  .should('contain', 'Name')
  .and('contain', 'Age')
  .and('contain', 'Weight')
  .and('contain', 'Height')
  .and('contain', 'Favorite Color')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: That works, but it could yield false positives if the data happens to be 'Age' for example.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yes, indeed. You could use the `.contains` method instead and pass a selector like so: `.contains('.my-item', 'Age')`.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you can do it in this way:

```
     const column = ['Name', 'Age', 'Weight', 'Height']

        column.forEach(function (value) {
            cy.get('.column')
              .children()
              .should('contain', value)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a regex like so:

```
function assertContainsMultiple(...msgs) {
  const containsRegex = new RegExp(msgs.join('.+'))
  cy.get('#msg').contains(containsRegex)
}
```

Partial credit to Github co-pilot--I had the idea, typed "const containsRegex" and it knew what I wanted. Nice.